# Migrate data from Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, drupal-7

I'm migrating a drupal website to Django, and I need to get the post (news) from my drupal installation... The question is: what tables do I need to read to do that?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this yourself? Pose some ideas, and perhaps someone will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the node table and also see all fields involved in your content type, drupal create a table by field, for example:

Content type News contains the following fields:

title
body
field_image

Then you need to read the following tables:

Node
field_data_body
field_data_field_image